# Indoor jump rope as a temporary supplement for long-distance running?

Tags: running, home-exercise, jump-rope

Due to very bad smog situation that will last at least couple of weeks, I can't go running outside. I was thinking I could supplement long distance running by some jump rope excercises at home. I am used to running 10km/1 hour regularly. I am not sure what kind of excercies should I do, never tried jump rope before (only as a kid).

- HIIT? Or just jump as long as I can?
- With running shoes? Or bare feet on yoga mat? I have hard floor
- Any special requirement for the jump rope?

I have read the following questions and I believe it could work, with proper routine:

- [What should I look for in a jump rope?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/10209/5944)
- [What is a jump rope good for?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/2265/5944)
- [Benefits of jogging/running versus rope skipping](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/4507/5944)

Comment: Just stopping by to say that jumping rope is great. I'm a runner like you, and recently picked up jumping rope. My recommendations re: equipment are there: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/41897/33155

Answer (score 3):

The smog coming from the forest fires in Indonesia will affect you inside as well as outside, unless you have air filters inside or you wear a suitable face mask (e.g. a mask with an N95 rating).

If you insist on working out inside and you can't find a treadmill to use somewhere then you can try jumping rope.  I would advise you to start jumping rope slowly, focusing on your skill.  Anytime you start a new physical activity you run the risk of injury because your body is not used to the new demands.

Here is a good article online about jumping rope: [Jump Rope Training](http://www.rossboxing.com/thegym/thegym26.htm)

This article recommends trying to do 20 second intervals without tripping on the rope, and building from there.

Comment: It's a compromise. I must do something. The quality of air inside my house is ok, better than in the nearby gym.